# Measuring the mic input volume during recording with AVAudioRecorder

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avfoundation

new here, and new to mobile dev in general. This question is more about approach than anything. I have a simple app that I’m writing to learn various things, one of which is `AVFoundation`. I have the app working to the point where I record audio using `AVAudioRecorder`, play the recorded file back with `AVAudioPlayer`, and all is well. There are two things I’d like to achieve but I’m not quite sure how to go about them in the best way. I'm using Swift 3, xcode 8.3, iOS 10.3. Lots of 3s.

First: I want to only play back X number of seconds of the audio. To achieve this, my thought is to use `scheduledTimer` for `X`, which will trigger a `stop()` call when it elapses. Is that the best method to use?

Second: I want to measure the decibel level of input coming into the microphone while it’s recording. This is the one I truly have little insight on how to accomplish. I believe this can be obtained through the `AVAudioRecorder.powerOutput` value (?), but I’m unclear as to how I can monitor the value during playback and act on it.

Not really sure what code to include since it's pretty basic. I'm setting up the `AVAudioSession` in the `AppDelegate`, the `AVAudioRecorder` is setup to record in `didFinishLoading`, and the rest of the record, stop, play functionality is through buttons.

Comment: use EZAudio library as it have all these functionality you want.

Comment: While I appreciate the suggestion, I'd rather be taught to fish than handed one (third party library). That library is also not written in Swift, and has been deprecated in favor of AudioKit, which is written in Swift.